# Windows 10 Samba server not detected OS X Lion

Tags: networking, osx-lion, samba, windows-10-v1709

I have a Windows 10 desktop which functions as the Samba server. When my Early 2008 MacBook, running Lion, attempts to connect, the connection always fails because it does not detect the server despite the server appearing in the side bar in Finder.

My networks (profiles both set to private):

[image]

Private network profile settings:

[image]

All network profile settings:

[image]

Hard drive share settings. I have four hard drives but the settings are all the same. Sharing for each has been enabled.

[image]

MacBook detects server but fails to connect. Using "connect as" also fails without ever prompting for login info.

[image]

Connecting manually by LAN IP address also fails:
[image]

The error I receive:

[image]

Could someone help me resolve this issue? It's really frustrating.

Comment: What version of SMB is your MacBook using.  SMBv1 is disabled by default on Windows 10

Comment: It's not really clear what version of SMB Lion uses. I read that OS X versions newer than Snow Leopard use a proprietary SMB solution. I suspect it might be a SMBv1 issue. I enabled all the SMBv1 services in Windows 10 and I'm restarting the server to test it.

Comment: Yes, enabling all the SMBv1 services in the Windows 10 features list fixed it!

Comment: That’s a absolutely horrible idea!  SMBv1 is extremely vulnerable.

Comment: I realize SMBv1 and Lion are both subjected to security issues. I'm a high school student and I don't have enough money now for anything better. I bought a nice laptop a while back but someone stole it. For the record, I don't recommend using obsolete software in relation to valuable information or resources. I could bootcamp Windows on the MacBook but I prefer to leave it with its native OS.

Answer (score 0):

As @ramhound mentioned, Windows 10 has SMBv1 disabled. It seems the 1709 Creator's Update changed some defaults with SMBv1.

As noted here (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/376307-mac-computer-fails-to-connect-to-a-server-via-smb), OS X versions newer than 10.6.8 use a proprietary SMB client which makes identifying the resembled SMB protocol more difficult. Apparently, the SMB client in Lion (10.7.5) is designed to resemble SMBv1.

Navigating to **Windows Features > SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support** and **Windows Features > SMB Direct** and enabling all sub services resolved my problem.

[image][image]